# looping through txt file to use specific part of a string

Tags: php

I am new to Php and can't seem to figure this out no matter how much I've googled.

So I've opened the txt file (which consists of multiple lines of this type of string unique Identifier IMEI in bold: 
Rx:00:39:54 06/09/2015:+RESP:GTEPS,210101,**863286020022449**,,8296,01,1,3,0.0,0,1031.1,29.367950,-30.799161,20150906003710,,,,,,2857.9,20150906003710,8038$) There are different strings with different IMEIs but i only want to use a specific one.

My question is, how do I extract/only use the string with the same Unique identifier and then loop through those to use in another function?
My function has different cases and each case has different calculations, so I'll need to loop through the txt file (with e.g. 863286020022449 as Identifier, ignoring other identifiers/IMEIs) in order to use the string in my function as below:

This is my starter function:

```
function GetParam($unknownFunction, $numberCommas) {
$returnString = "";
$foundSting = 0;
$numberFound = 0;
$len = strlen($unknownFunction);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
if ($Rawline[$i] == ",") {
++$numberFound;
if ($numberFound > $numberCommas)
break;
if ($numberFound == $numberCommas)
$foundSting = 1;
}
else if ($foundSting == 1) {
$returnString .= $unknownFunction[$i];
}
}
return $returnString;
echo $returnString;
}

$i = strpos($unknownFunction, ":GT");
$p = substr($unknownFunction, $i+3,3);

$Protocol = GetParam($unknownFunction, 1);
```

//this switch reads the differences in the message types (e.g. HBD- in this case is a heartbeat message type and would thus have a different amount of commas in the string and has different definitions of the characters within the commas)
   switch ($p) {
      case 'HBD':
         //+ACK:GTHBD,220100,135790246811220,,20100214093254,11F0$
         //This is an example of an HBD message

```
     $result2["Type"] = 'Heart beat';
     $IMEI = GetParam($unknownFunction, 2); 
     $mDate = GetParam($unknownFunction, 4);
     $mDate = substr($mDate,0,4).'-'.substr($mDate,4,2).'- 
     '.substr($mDate,6,2).' 
     '.substr($mDate,8,2).':'.substr($mDate,10,2).':'.substr($mDate,12,2);
     break;
```

This is the biggest problem I am facing at the moment and when I print the different lines, it indicates the correct IMEI but it does not loop through the whole file to use each string that belongs to that IMEI.

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you so much.

Example of input file:

```
Rx:00:00:00 28/02/2018:+RESP:GTFRI,3C0103,862045030241360,,14067,11,1,1,29.7,320,151.1,30.949307,-29.819685,20180227235959,0655,0001,013A,87B6,00,35484.1,01500:51:31,,,100,220101,,,,20180228000000,3461$
Rx:00:00:01 28/02/2018:+RESP:GTERI,380201,869606020047340,gv65,00000002,14076,10,1,1,119.0,119,24.3,18.668516,-34.016808,20180227235955,0655,0001,00F7,2DC9,00,98912.0,02235:20:25,0,100,220101,0,0,20180227235958,FF20$
Rx:00:00:03 28/02/2018:+RESP:GTERI,380201,869606020162990,,00000002,12912,10,1,1,0.0,230,1127.3,30.846671,-27.674206,20180227235956,0655,0001,013E,88B0,00,106651.1,03546:44:42,0,100,210101,0,0,20180227235959,6190$
Rx:00:00:03 28/02/2018:+ACK:GTHBD,450102,865084030005340,gb100,20180228000003,CC61$
Rx:00:00:03 28/02/2018:+RESP:GTERI,380201,869606020115980,,00000002,13640,10,1,1,12.1,353,1663.1,28.580726,-28.162208,20180227235957,,,,,,37599.6,02422:07:24,0,100,220101,0,0,20180228000000,1937$
Rx:00:00:04 28/02/2018:+RESP:GTERI,380502,869606020276840,gv65,00000002,12723,10,1,1,0.0,106,1232.8,22.878013,-27.951762,20180227235952,0655,0001,0204,63C5,00,13808.9,00778:32:20,0,100,210100,0,0,20180228000002,2C50$
Rx:00:00:04 28/02/2018:+RESP:GTERI,380502,869606020274530,gv65,00000002,12683,10,1,1,0.0,91,1213.7,24.863444,-28.174319,20180227235956,0655,0001,0203,69F1,00,9753.2,00673:49:21,0,100,210100,0,0,20180228000003,8AC7$
Rx:00:00:05 28/02/2018:+ACK:GTHBD,380201,863286023083810,,20180228000003,0D87$
Rx:00:00:06 28/02/2018:+RESP:GTFRI,3C0103,862045030241360,,14086,10,1,1,34.0,327,152.0,30.949152,-29.819501,20180228000002,0655,0001,013A,87B6,00,35484.1,01500:51:36,,,100,220101,,,,20180228000005,3462$
Rx:00:00:06 28/02/2018:+ACK:GTHBD,060228,862894021626380,,20180228000007,F9A5$
Rx:00:00:07 28/02/2018:+RESP:GTERI,380201,869606020019430,,00000002,12653,10,1,1,0.0,219,1338.7,26.882063,-28.138099,20180228000002,,,,,,86473.7,05645:48:34,0,93,210101,0,0,20180228000003,0FA5$
Rx:00:00:09 28/02/2018:+ACK:GTHBD,380502,869606020233940,gv65,20180228000008,7416$
Rx:00:00:10 28/02/2018:+RESP:GTAIS,380201,869606020171710,,11,11,1,1,0.0,95,281.2,30.855164,-29.896575,20180228000009,0655,0001,0156,9A9F,00,156073.7,20180228000008,F9A4$
```

Each GT message means something which is why i need to extract only one specific IMEI and use the result in my function as a breakdown of what every set of numbers between the commas actually mean. The end result needs to be populated in an excel spreadsheet but that's a different issue.

Comment: I would suggest renaming the variable `$unknownFunction` to something else as the name is misleading.

Comment: Thank you but that's the result of the loop I need to get the answers. I don't know what it is hence the "Unknown" part.

Comment: Is it possible to format the question and put some simple lines for file content? I think it will be useful to see how exactly input file looks like.

Comment: Hi Zhorov, I've added some of the input file. Each line is separated by a space. Not sure if that's useful. I have thought of putting the strings in an array but I'm at a loss as to how to use the loop of an array in my function.

Answer (score 0):

Nested foreach, keeping tracking of the IMEIs you've already gone through. Or something like this.

```
<?php

 $filename = 'info.txt';
 $contents = file($filename);

 foreach ($contents as $line) {

     $doneAlreadyArray = array();
     $IMEI = GetParam($line, 2); 

     foreach ($contents as $IMEIline){

         $thisIMEI = GetParam($IMEIline,2);

         //check if already done the IMEI previously
         if (!in_array($thisIMEI, $doneAlreadyArray)){
             //matching IMEIs?
             if ($thisIMEI == $IMEI){ 
                 //run new function with entire $IMEIline
                 new_function($IMEIline);
              }
          }
      }

      //add IMEI to doneAlreadyArray
      array_push($doneAlreadyArray,$IMEI); 
 } 

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question right and you want to extract the string(line) with the same Unique identifier, this may be useful for your needs as a strating point.
The example is very basic, and use data from your question:

```
<?php
// Read the file.
$filename = 'input.txt';
$file = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

// Each item of $output will contain an array of lines:
$output = array();
foreach ($file as $row) {
    $a = explode(',', $row);
    $imei = $a[2];
    if (!array_key_exists($imei, $output)) {
        $output[$imei] = array();
    }
    $output[$imei][] = $row;
}

// Then do what you want ...
foreach ($output as $key=>$value) {
    echo 'IMEI: '.$key.'</br>';
    foreach($value as $row) {
        // Here you can call your functions. I just echo the row:
        echo $row.'</br>';
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the feedback.
Ryan Dewberry ended up helping me.
The fix was simpler than I thought too :)

```
//Unknownfunction is now $line

function GetParam($line, $numberCommas) {
$returnString = "";
$foundSting = 0;
$numberFound = 0;
$len = strlen($line);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
      if ($line[$i] == ",") {
            ++$numberFound;
            if ($numberFound > $numberCommas)
                  break;
            if ($numberFound == $numberCommas)
                  $foundSting = 1;
      }
      else if ($foundSting == 1) {
            $returnString .= $line[$i];
      }
}
return $returnString;
// print $returnString;
}
//this is new - makes sure I use the correct IMEI
$contents = file($fileName);

foreach ($contents as $line){

$haveData = 0;
$IMEI = GetParam($line, 2); 

if ($IMEI == $gprsid){

$i = strpos($line, ":GT");
$p = substr($line, $i+3,3);
$Protocol = GetParam($line, 1);

//this is the part I struggled with as well - This is an array of all of my 
//calculation 
//results and in printing it out I can see that everything is working

$superResult = array();

  array_push($superResult,$result2);

print_r($superResult);

}
}
```

Much appreciated. Thank you!